# Is there any alternative to WebViews in android?

Tags: android, webview, crosswalk

I am building an Android app and I using Traditional WebViews to load the web pages. I was wondering if there is any alternative to WebViews which can make the loading of web pages faster.

I read about https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about.html but found that it increases the app size by ~50MB.
Also, it only increases the web loading speed by 10-15% only and is buggy.

If there is no alternative, is there any way to make WebViews faster?

Thanks in advance.

Down vote must accompany reason.

Comment: Figure out what is slowing it down and optimize that.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the "richness" of the web content that you're trying to load.

The standard Android `TextView` actually supports rendering a small subset of HTML, by calling `setText(Html.fromHtml("This will be <strong>bold</strong> text"));`

But if it's anything more complex than that (e.g. tables, javascript, css, etc) you're stuck with a `WebView`. However, the performance of WebViews should be quite good (very near native speed), unless the web page itself is very heavy and slows the WebView down. You should do some profiling of your web content to see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the bottleneck can be how the webpage is designed and not the webview?

Comment: @Kanika Absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to interact with the page you can use **[Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)**.  It includes features to warmup and pre-fetch the page so that it appears to work extremely fast for the user.  If you use it this way it is faster than launching an external browser and faster than loading a WebView.

Comment: I need to interact with the webpage and it has to be from the app only.